# How do I find the length of a number using NCalc built- in functions?

Tags: java, c#, c, math, ncalc

I am using NCalc in my project to evaluate expressions. The framework includes a set of already implemented functions which can be found [here](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=functions&referringTitle=Home).

I am interested in calculating the length of a number or a string. Can I achieve that using just the built-in functions?

Comment: Look at `Log10`, see if that has enough precision to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting length of an *integer* number, you can do something like this-

```
int length = ceiling(log10(number));
```

But a method like this will be much efficient-

```
int countLength(int number){
    if(number>9) return countLength(number/10) + 1;
    return 1;
}
```